# Elasticsearch - calculations on date fields

Tags: date, elasticsearch, calculation

I'm trying to prepare ES query which will return all records that have `firstDate + duration < secondDate`

Problem is that I have only `duration` value at the moment of constructing query and both `firstDate` and `secondDate` are fields in resource. So ES would have to calculate it and return matching records. It would be easy to do that in SQL but not in ES afaik.

I couldn't find any native solution. I met some examples in `painless` but I don't think it's best solution to do that.

One of my idea is to prepare query and limit results as much as I can and filter records in code but to be honest I'm not sure about the performance impact of this "solution".

For now, I don't know how many records there will be so I have to be prepared for everything.

Could you tell me if it's possible to do that in ES and if yes then how?